# updating Microsoft IdentityModel packages to 6.23x suddenly adding 10 more package dependencies

Tags: .net, visual-studio, package, nuget, identitymodel

Anyone experience an unexpected issue when upgrading your IdentityModel package dependencies?  Is this a "bug" or is there another way to get around this?

I have several .NET 4.8.1 framework console apps that have a dependency on the IdentityModel package, which has always been a collection of these packages:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens 
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging       
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens       
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
```

Our most recent packages were on 6.19. Nuget showed that 6.23.1 was available.  So I let it "update" the packages... which suddenly pulled in MANY more packages (that were NOT shown as dependencies):

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions   
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces          
System.Buffers                         
System.Memory                          
System.Numerics.Vectors                
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 
System.Text.Encoding                   
System.Text.Encodings.Web              
System.Text.Json                       
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions      
System.ValueTuple
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

We can see the difference between the dependencies of the two versions：

**6.19.0**
[image]
**6.26.1**
[image]

And when we update this package we can see that:
[image]

So I think this is normal, it is caused by the change in the dependencies of the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens package

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I think this confirms that a LOT of new dependencies were added, but I don't consider this a "good answer"... the dependency chain seems to be getting a bit out of control.  DLL-heck has returned.